# Monitor windows startup process

Tags: windows-7, boot, monitoring, malware-detection

My win7 starts up pretty slow lately.

I think it's some kind of malware, but my antivirus software doesn't pick up anything.

How could i monitor the startup processes myself? It seems to me like either something's doing a lot of work, or some important windows process hangs for a while, since there's stuff that i can do while it's starting (like start a console), and stuff that i can't do (like execute the `systeminfo` command in the console)

So if you happen to know how i can monitor my system, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Autoruns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) is a good tool to find out *what* is loaded on startup, but it's not fully suited for troubleshooting startup performance issues. Not all by itself, that is. I'd suggest using [`Process Monitor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) as well, with boot logging enabled. Also you should check the performance diagnostics eventlog (`Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Diagnostics-Performance\Operational`) for events with ID 100. See [here](http://itexpertvoice.com/home/what%E2%80%99s-taking-so-long-how-to-fight-slow-startup-times-in-windows-7/) for a comprehensive troubleshooting guide.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), it shows a complete list of services and processes which are scheduled to run at start up. It also allows you to disable any process from auto start.